# How to Implement top and bottom tab bar in android

Tags: android, tabs, tabbar

What is the easiest way to implement top and bottom tab bar ,i searched a lot.can anybody help me to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create swap-able tab bar then please use sample on below link: 
1.

1.http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/
2.http://javapapers.com/android/android-tab-layout-with-swipe-views/
3.https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

for bottom, use 3rd link :

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

bottom of view.

For non swap-able use sample on below link:

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html
http://javapapers.com/android/android-tab-layout-tutorial/
 if you want to create bottom tab bar then use:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

please use sample :
http://envyandroid.com/align-tabhost-at-bottom/

Comment: How to add two tab host in one layout

Comment: use link : http://androidcodeblogspot.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-fragment-tab-example-bottom.html